# Simulate drag & drop file to website in VBA

Tags: vba, drag-and-drop, simulate

I have an Access database that uses VBA code to generate a GPX map file. That works fine. I then want the contents of the GPX file to be displayed on a website, https://mapy.cz
The method that the site authors intend is for users to open the site, then manually drag and drop GPX files onto the site, at which point the contents are read in and displayed by the website. This also works fine.

What I want to do is NOT require my database user to open a browser, locate the file and drag it onto the browser by hand. I want my VBA code to not only create this GPX file, but also open the user's default browser, direct it to this mapping site (all this also works okay), but then SIMULATE or FORCE the drag and drop action FROM MY VBA CODE. That is the part that on which I'm floundering. I've looked up things like using VBA's IE.Document object, and it seems to me that it should be in there somewhere, but I can't find anything that makes sense to me.

I've done similar things in the past, with SendKeys to simulate the user typing, and AutoIT to code-control a running DOS application, including reading the programs responses from the DOS screen and forcing in commands, all from VBA. It seems to me that this should be possible, and not even all that uncommon a requirement, but I've not located anything helpful in all my searching, and I've done a lot. Maybe I'm simply phrasing my searches wrong, but at this point, I'm just flat stuck.

Comment: Read the website source/elements and find the id/input/tag that updates the file path and name when you drag and drop it. Dragging and dropping is nothing but a shortcut to a file select dialog, which goes into a form or an input, find that in the html code, use VBA to update the value of that ID with the file path and use VBA to "submit" to the next page. Unless this website is a Java applet, it should be doable, a Java applet is much more complex and sometimes just not possible to manipulate.

Comment: I don't see anything like an 'input' tag anywhere in the HTML. It does have a fair amount of scripting - about 500 lines out of 600 total are script.

Would that mean API programming? That is also on my list of things I need to learn, but haven't yet.

Comment: I also notice now that they have a some clickable elements that lead to a standard file selection dialog. But I do not see the labels on the control anywhere in the page's source code. Is there some way to remotely activate those? That would serve just as well.

Comment: `iedoc.getelementsbyclassname("shitem si-importXML")(0).click` The problem is that you will have to paste the file name and path on the selection dialog. not pretty but doable.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm afraid I still don't understand. The clickable button on the map seems to be generated by JAVA, as  it is not in the HTML anywhere. A minor popup menu appears on the map when this is clicked, then that as one option opens a file select dialog. There is nothing in the source code with the text 'XML', 'GPX', 'Input' or anything else that I have been able to identify as belonging to this functionality.

Comment: The HTML source will probably not have any of that, it probably brings all that from other files or Javascript, so the main source will not have it. You have to inspect the elements and you can find much more that the source doesnt show. The class name i gave you on my previous post is the one you have to click on and it will open the file dialog.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/WP20dAi this is in google Chrome. but it also works in IE 11 with inspect element.

Comment: Okay, that is some progress. I ran code that opened the page and tried this iedoc...click line, but got an error. I went back and manually clicked the button that opened the popup window and executed the line again, and the file dialog window opened!

So, many thanks - that has gotten me onto a functioning track. I still need to get the popup open in the first place, and then I need to load the file path and name, but I'm miles ahead of where I was. I'll post back with my progress as I go.

Comment: in that case it means that you have to click the "Tools" button first in the page. `iedoc.getelementsbyclassname("icon tools")(0).click`

Comment: That works perfectly - you're a wizard. How do you know what to pick out of the web page so accurately, and what commands to execute to get it done? And what do you think is the best way to now load the path and filename? Would you use SendKeys, or is there a more elegant way to get the information into the page and click the Open button in the Select File dialog?

Comment: With this approach, send keys would be the easiest way. Add a timer of 2 or 3 seconds to let the dialog open and then send keys the whole path.

Comment: Copy and Paste may also work. Try copying the value of a cell and pasting it on the dialog. Or using Object Forms to copy to the clipboard and paste it.

Comment: Thought I was there, with this:

ieDoc.getelementsbyclassname("icon tools")(0).Click
ieDoc.getelementsbyclassname("shitem si-importXML")(0).Click

but when I execute the second statement, the code hangs, waiting for a response from that dialog box, and refuses to go further until I do something manually to dismiss that dialog.

Comment: It seems like there should be a way to force in whatever text the dialog box brings back in normal use, but I'm not having any luck locating where something like that would be.

Comment: One of the things that occurred to me is to start a vbscript process that would execute the SendKeys command into this dialog, but that seems like an extremely ugly way to do it.

Comment: Just tried it, and the VBScript code SendKeys command does send in the proper text and closes the dialog box, but I can't believe there isn't a better way of doing it. For one thing, there is no equivalent of DoEvents in VBScript, so I would have to activate the script before calling the importXML click command and let it run at 100% while continually scanning for this dialog box to appear. That's just gross.

Comment: Yup, it's not pretty to deal with a Dialog Box from another App/Program in VBA. Digging more into the website code can eventually get you to the point where the dialog box is not needed, but this means you have to dig into reading the javascript to get to the function that submits the filename. You may also end up at a dead end where there is no function to process the file and it's all server handled, wasting time reading the javascript.

Comment: Well, thank you for the help to this point. I don't like it, but I may have to just live with my VBScript gremlin - at least it works.

Can you point me to some resources that might help me dig through the website's code? You obviously know a good deal about it, since you were so easily able to identify the necessary points in the code to activate the dialog. I'd like to at least try for a while, to see if I can make any more progress - I hate just giving up.